# hover over child to make parent bigger css

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, flexbox

I want to hover over div2 and make container bigger, but for some reason hover doesnt work, any idea ? is it with :has() ? any help is appreciated

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box > .box-inside {
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-top:40%;
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

  
  
/* when div2 is hovered make container bigger */
.container:has(#div2:hover) .container {
transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: all 1s;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">


<div class="box">
  <div class="box-inside" id="div2">div2
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: .container:has(#div2:hover) .container remove .container at the end .container:has(#div2:hover) check this

Answer (score 1):

Because your selector `.container:has(#div2:hover) .containe` selects the container inside the container. Simply remove the second `.container` selector:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box > .box-inside {
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-top:40%;
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

  
  
/* when div2 is hovered make container bigger */
.container:has(#div2:hover) {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">


<div class="box">
  <div class="box-inside" id="div2">div2
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

Please note that [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility) does not work in some browsers, e.g. Firefox

Comment: Then ould you possibly give another way doing this instead of :has() ?

Comment: @walee Using JS events